# URL Forwarding or CNAME for github pages

Tags: dns, subdomain

I've set up a github page with a custom subdomain like `sub.abc.com`, and I also want the domain `abc.com` redirects to the subdomain(show **subdomain** in the browser's address bar). So, which method should I take, 302 URL Forwarding or CNAME? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got an answer form github's technical support staff via email, and he said that I should use URL Forwarding rather than CNAME. Hope this can be helpful for others who meet the same problem.